# Compute string constant at compile time with ternary operator

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Q: Is there a way to make the sample below compile in C# or something similar in spirit?

```
public class Switch
{
    public const bool Value = true;
}

public class A
{
    private const string Id = "foo" + (Switch.Value ? "Dev" : String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: You could `#ifdef` `#else` together with a conditional compilation symbol (which you would set in your project build setting) to both set the values of `Switch.Value` and `A.ID` without using using expressions...

Comment: I think you want use [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) in this case instead of const

Comment: @Reniuz a preprocessor directive is no option because I would to have to set it for multiple projects in the solution which is tedious.

Comment: All of this code is compiled at the same time, right? You're not changing `Switch.Value` in one project, rebuilding **only that project** and expect `A.Id` to change?

Comment: @participant fair enough. It depends on use case.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Even tough all of us hit "build solution" every time this might introduce a nasty pitfall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is `String.Empty`, which is not a `const` expression, even though it will always evaluate to `""`.

So if you try this:

```
public class Switch
{
    public const bool Value = true;
}

public class A
{
    private const string Id = "foo" + (Switch.Value ? "Dev" : "");
}
```

it should compile right away, at least it does in C# 7.3.

---

Note that `const` **really** mean *constant*.

For instance, if you put the above two classes in two different projects, rebuild both, then go and change `Switch.Value` to *false*, and **only rebuild that project**, then `A.Value` will stay put, it will not "re-evaluate", because that was done at the time that was built.

It is generally not a good idea to use `const` for anything that isn't **really** constant, except if you're always rebuilding the whole solution, everything, the whole application, at the same time, then it *might* be OK.

However I would still use a `readonly` field/property for this, instead of a `const`.

Comment: What a goof - you're right! I accept your answer in 3 minutes :)